# android sdk missing hints like "context", "text" in parentheses

Tags: android, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX6gM.png)

I accidentally turned off the "context" type hints and have been trying to turn it back on for an hour, who knows how to do it. thank you very much

Comment: Search for "inlay hints" or "parameter hints" in the Settings menu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I faced the same problem. In xml editor there are no longer hints for id, text ect. Very inconvenient... Please let us know if you solved the issue!